# Connecting current sense transformer directly to MCU/ADC vs using an OpAmp

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-measurement

I am currently designing a circuit where a current sense transformer is used to measure the current in a flyback transformer. The current sense transformer is connected in series with the flyback transformer. The current I need to sense has a peak of 25A.

Now I am seeing 2 options to achieve what I want. Both involve a reference voltage of 1/2 Vcc which is connected to the current sense transformer. One involves an additional Op-Amp, the other one involves a direct connection to the MCU. What are the advantages/disadvantages of these solutions?

I can choose a turns ratio from 1:20, 1:30, 1:40, 1:50, 1:60, 1:70, 1:100, 1:125. Which one is best suited for this case? I assume with an opamp I will have to choose a different one than without the opamp?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUAZwg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You might want to correct the positive feedback on your op-amp, and the low value feedback resistor.

Comment: @JohnD Thanks, I have changed it

Comment: The transformer saturates. You need a diode in series with the burden resistor, to complement the diode (or single action switch) in series with the primary. Assuming this is how you're using it -- please show more of your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A peak of **25A** in a ***flyback***?  Very brave.  :-)

Assuming the 25A is indeed correct (are you missing a decimal point here, perhaps?), then let's first sort out the CT ratio you need:  you will want a very high turns ratio to keep the secondary current as low as possible.  For a peak of 25A I would suggest 100:1 as a minimum, which gives 250mA as the peak secondary current.  However, as the turns-ratio goes up, so too does leakage inductance which may cause bandwidth to reduce, hence response time to increase - it depends on the exact model of CT you choose.

Next, convert that secondary current to a voltage that is in the range you need. Without an op-amp, you probably want the peak to match the maximum input voltage of the ADC.  Let's assume that is 3V, so that gives:
R = 3V / 250mA = 12ohm.
Yes, 12 ohm, not 100 ohm.  And the power dissipated by that R at 25A primary will be:
P = V * I = 3V * 0.25A = 0.75W.
This power loss may be a little on the high side, so you may want to consider an even higher turns ratio, say, 200:1, or even 500:1 (with the caveats mentioned earlier about slower response times).

If the voltage required at the MCU/ADC input is achievable by simply selecting a suitable resistor that does not experience too much power dissipation, then there should be no need to use an opamp.  You should only need an opamp if the voltage on the resistor has to be kept small (much less than full-scale ADC input V) in order to keep its power dissipation within limits.

My next concern is: Why the 1.65V bias?  Yes, I know that is so that the ADC can sense both positive and ***negative*** signals, but if you are monitoring the current in the primary winding of a flyback then, please be advised: negative current should **not** happen. Ever.  If it does happen, then you have **much** bigger problems than not being able to sense it.  :-)

UPDATE 2023-08-28:  This update was done after more details emerged via the discussion in the comments section below this answer.

The OP has disclosed the circuit, it was obtained from a Paper, refer image below copied from:
[image]

Reference for the Paper:
Hasan, R., Hassan, W., Farhangi, M., Mekhilef, S., & Xiao, W. (2019).
Enhanced soft-switching strategy for flyback-based microinverter in PV power systems.
IET Renewable Power Generation, 13(15), 2830-2839.

Link:
https://ietresearch.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1049/iet-rpg.2019.0307

In regards to the control scheme proposed in that paper, the turn-off instant of the main switch Sm is determined by its current (Ism), however turn-off of the auxiliary switch (Sc) & hence turn-on of Sm is determined by a clock, **not** the current;  refer the Paper page 6:

> The main switch current iSm compares with the reference signal
> iref∗.  When this current is equal to the reference signal, the PWM
> gate signals become low, and hence the switch Sm is turned off. The
> gate signal of the main switch Sm is again turned on maintaining a
> constant switching frequency.

Therefore, monitoring the current in the resonant inductor is **not** required for the control scheme presented in the paper.  Hence, it will be possible to control this converter by the simplest form of current detection possible: a resistor (let's call it "Ri") that monitors the current flowing in the main switch, which is placed in the source leg of main MOSFET (Sm). Furthermore, since one end of Ri is connected to GND, galvanic isolation of this signal is not necessary.

To keep the power loss of Ri small, the voltage across it must be kept small, say, about 100mV max, meaning the value of this resistor will be quite small, about 3.3mohm (assuming 30A at 0.1V), ie: 1W peak, but much less than this for a typical cycle when you convert peak-to-RMS for a triangle wave.  Note that monitoring the voltage across this resistor will require all the usual PCB track layout tricks associated with burden resistors in a high di/dt environment: use "Kelvin sensing", treat the wires as transmission lines, and provide a compensation capacitor to null out the inductance.

An op-amp will be required to amplify this signal up to levels that the MCU/ADC can use, eg: 3V peak, so a gain of about 30 is required.  For the switching frequency mentioned in this paper, this should be quite easy to achieve with opamps having GBWP~20MHz, and slew-rates of ~10V/us.

This will not require any biasing of the signal, and you can supply the op-amp from a single power supply rail thus keeping things simple.  Provided the opamp recovers well after a negative input (as most modern op-amps do), then there will be no need to have a diode (or similar component) to prevent the negative voltage across Ri from appearing at the op-amp input.

In other words: you can use the simplest means to monitor current: a resistor, followed by a good amplifier.

My suggestions for proceeding from here:

1. Simulate the circuit and the proposed control scheme, and gain a good understanding of how it works.
2. Simulate the effect of real-world PCB tracks, eg: what effect will a small amount of L have when placed in series with (a) Cdc, (b) Ri  (c) Cf (secondary side).  This will help identify which parts of the PCB layout are important to get right.
3. Use a current probe to observe the current in Lr during the testing of the converter, rather than trying to fit a CT for this purpose into your PCA.

Best of luck.

Comment: Note that a diode on the secondary side is necessary to ensure reset flux.

Comment: @TimWilliams  Yes, agreed.  I was waiting for clarity regarding the rest of the system this is connected to, where exactly this current sensor is being deployed in a flyback converter, and what it is being used for (control, protection, monitoring), before getting into the nitty-gritty of how to ensure the current CT core is reset correctly.  Still don't know if this is going on the primary winding, or the secondary - and how many secondaries there are.  Cheers.

Comment: @FabioBarone The 25A are indeed correct. I am stepping up voltage, so a high primary current and a low secondary current are used in this case. I am operating at 50kHz and it is a resonant active clamp Flyback. My idea was to measure the current going through the flyback, which will be negative at some point due to the resonancy. I don't think I am actually interested in the negative current though, so I might be able to just filter it by using a diode on the output of the CT.

Comment: @Jenny  May I suggest sharing the entire schematic, along with the proposed location of the CT, the community can help you better with that information.  What is the reason to use a CT rather than just a resistor in the primary current path, is galvanic isolation required?

Comment: @FabioBarone What I am trying to build is the converter from https://doi.org/10.1049/iet-rpg.2019.0307 , just with a slightly lower power (they have a peak current of 34 A). I wanted to place the current transformer between Lr and Lm (so between the resonant inductor and the transformer), simply because that is convenient on the PCB. Additionally this placement allows me to connect an oscilloscope and see the transformer current when implementing the control algorithm. Do you think a resistor between the MOSFET and GND would be better suited here and have lower losses/easier handling?

Comment: @Jenny Now that I see the circuit I think I can assist, however, I am going to sleep now.  Have you simulated the circuit and the control scheme?  It would make sense to do that, and learn as much as you can, before implementing a physical circuit.   From what I see in the paper, the control scheme monitors the current in main MOSFET Sm, it does not need to monitor the current in the resonant inductor Lr.  This means a resistor in the source current of the MOSFET may be suitable, no need for a CT.

Comment: @FabioBarone I haven't done any simulations yet. It appears that they switch on, wait until the current reaches the wanted threshold, then turn it off, turn on the auxilary switch with a certain dead time. The next turn on is solely based on time apparently. A resistor on the MOSFET would mean I need an opamp again as otherwise the power dissipation would be way to high. I would need 1.2 mOhms there, which would mean 0.03 V, and I would still have to filter out the negative current using a diode. I still think a current transformer and directly connecting it might be the best choice here.

Comment: Also what seems to be a little weird is that in Fig. 6 they show a linear rising current, and in Fig. 15 the current has valleys, which would mean I need to detect those and synchronize my switching to those valleys for best efficiency. I have no clue where those valleys are coming from though. It could only be from Cr, but the MOSFET is parallel to it and conducting,

Comment: @Jenny  RE: Fig 15: You are correct, the paper does not explain the ringing visible in the MOSGET current waveform, and this feature is not shown in the "simulation" or "theoretical" results of Fig 6.  However, I would suggest not trying to time the exact switch OFF instant of Sm with any part of this ringing eg: the valleys of Ism, as that will lead to control instability.  

I will modify my answer above after this discussion in the comments section.

Comment: @FabioBarone Wow, what a great answer!! Thank you so much.

Comment: Just one small follow-up-question: Should Cr be connected to the shunt aswell or should I go directly to GND with it? I think I could go directly to GND as it doesn't affect the current I want to measure?

Comment: @Jenny  Whether the current in Ri includes the current in Cr or not: In terms of using the sensed current to determine **when** to turn off Sm it makes no difference since the current in Cr when Sm is ON is zero.    

However, it may affect the **practicalities** of the current sensing system, since the current in Cr is bi-directional and would be much larger (I expect) than the current in the parasitic capacitance of Sm.  So, for example, it may affect how the opamp recovers from a negative signal.

Comment: Again, simulation is key to understanding how the circuit behaves for all the corner cases of operation (including faults), which will then inform the design the various subsystems, of which the current sensor is just one.  Best of luck with it, let us know how it goes.  Cheers.